# Why doesnt cout print anything?

Tags: c++, pointers, char

I am trying to output the char in my linked list in the following code but my `cout` in `printList` function wont print anything. I am not able to keep a finger on exactly the reason why and how can I get to print my char in the linkedlist.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

typedef struct linkedListNode{
    char obj;
    linkedListNode *next;
}node;

void insertLinkedList(char *p,node *head){
    node *end = head;
    while(*p != '\0'){
        node *temp = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
        temp -> obj = *p;
        end -> next = temp;
        end = temp;
        p++;
    }
}


void printList(node *head){
    node *temp = head;
    while(temp){
        cout << temp->obj << ",";
        temp = temp -> next;
    }
}

int main() {
    node *HEAD = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
    char p[] = "nitin";
    insertLinkedList(p,HEAD);
    printList(HEAD);
    return 0;
}
```

If my debugging skill are not failing me the list does get populated. Please help.

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code outputs everything just as you told it to, but it triggers undefined behavior once `printList` falls of the end of the list.

Firstly, you never initialize the `next` pointer of a new node, meaning that your list is not properly terminated. It actually prints everything properly, but it does not *stop* printing properly, since your list is not terminated. You have to remember to set the `next` pointer of the very last new element to null pointer. (That applies to head element as well.)

Secondly, standard output is line-buffered. Do not forget to output `std::endl` to see the actual output on the screen.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to terminate your linked list, so the app crashes.  When I run this on Windows 8.1 using VS2013, I actually see the output before the crash.  But that might be good luck.  On another machine/configuration it might crash before the console output is flushed so you might never see that it actually did work.

```
void insertLinkedList(char *p, node *head){
    node *end = head;
    while (*p != '\0'){
        node *temp = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
        temp->obj = *p;
        end->next = temp;
        end = temp;
        p++;
    }
    end->next = NULL;
}
```

Stepping through the code in a debugger should make it clear what is happening.

Comment: I released that when I posted. I am sorry.